# Union all tables with same names from different schemas in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am looking to create a union all on tables with same names in different schema.

Is there a way to do this in redshift other than a brute force method of naming individual tables and columns in the union all statement.

example:
schema z table a,
schema y table a,
schema x table a

schema z table b,
schema y table b

schema y table c,
schema x table c

tables a columns - d, e, f,g , h
table b columns - d,e,g,h,i
table c columns - d,e,f

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with writing a Lambda function (or just code on your computer) to inspect the system tables for the existence of the tables in question and then find the columns of each table.  Then this code would compose the SQL.

You could also likely do this in a stored procedure but this is likely more work to get running.  If you need many people to be able to use from inside the DB then it is worth the effort otherwise I'd go simple.